# Get Hotmail Address book By Passing User Credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-live

Can anyone help me to get Hotmail contact list by passing user credentials.
any code will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the [Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windowslive) you need the windows live SDK as a prerequisite as well

Comment: How Can i replace the redirect_uri with localhost to test the response.

Comment: i want to send the user credentials using my textbox and password field not as a hotmail dialog
like www.dropbox.net invitations.

Comment: is it YOUR credentials you are trying to send or another persons?

Comment: no i am trying to get address book emails for any user name and password

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the Live SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx

Comment: i want to send the user credentials using my textbox and password field not as a hotmail dialog
like www.dropbox.net invitations.